# What is the best method to replace image in footer for WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

What is the best method to replace the image in the footer for WordPress given the following code in the footer.php in WordPress? I would like to have a different image from the "main_logo". Keep in mind I have uploaded the image to the Media section of WordPress, and it has provided me with the URL for that image.

```
        <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || 
          !dynamic_sidebar('Bottom 1')) : ?><?php endif; ?>

        <?php 
        $logo = $data['main_logo'];
        $disable_footer_logo = $data['disable_footer_logo'];
         ?>
        <?php if($disable_footer_logo!="Yes") : ?>

        <?php 
        if($logo!=""){
            $img_url = $logo;
        }else{
            $img_url = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/logo2.png';    
        }

        ?>

        <img src="<?php echo $img_url; ?>" alt="" class="img-left" />

         <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: IMO the best thing to do would be to find out where `$data['main_logo']` comes from. It is probably a theme setting. Then you can just update that setting with your new logo.

Comment: I actually have tried. The image is actually broken online, and it has been deleted from my access, so tracking it is a little hard. Anyways, I would just like to replace that line of code with the best way to use the new image I have uploaded.

Comment: I'm using a way that works. Using img src in a text widget. It's probably not the best method, but if anyone chimes in with a better method, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `$logo = $data['main_logo'];` with `$logo = get_template_directory_uri().'/images/your_image.png'`, Assuming your image is located in images folder.